# Is max deadlift plus bodyweight a good approximation for max leg press?

Tags: deadlifts, bodyweight

I do not have easy access to a leg press machine but it would be interesting to know what my maximum leg press is, which is what I believe to be the strongest movement one can usually exert force-wise.

I thought a good approximation for this would be bodyweight plus max deadlift. The reason for this is that is equal to the normal force the ground is exerting during a deadlift and that the lifter has to overcome.

Is this reasoning correct? Is it generally the case that bodyweight plus max deadlift is approximately equal to max leg press?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*No.*

They're completely different movement patterns, and there is too much variation between the two to derive any kind of comparison.

Leg Press numbers are typically a lot higher because it isolates the legs specifically. The athlete is also locked in place and very stable. The range-of-motion for the legs is a lot larger, and is more quad focused.

In contrast, a deadlift is a full-body free-weight exercise in which the athlete provides the stability. The legs do provide a lot of drive, but from a shorter range of motion.

Comment: My max deadlift at 185 pounds is 455 (adds up to 640), but I can leg press 765 for sets of 10 all day.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Actually now that I think about it, my max deadlift + bodyweight is 880 lbs (655 @ 225), and the most I've ever leg pressed was 765 x 8. Calculators claim I could do 950 x 1, but it's not something I have any desire to find out.